# Unset elements from an array in tcl

Tags: arrays, tcl

I am creating an **array** in TCL for which the input should be a series of numbers. **The first
two elements of the array is supposed to carry the information for deletion of the elements present inside the array**. First element must carry the index of the element
occupying the array where the deletion should start with and the second element
carry the index of the element occupying the array up to which the deletion should
progress.

I am kind of new to TCL and tried the below code but facing errors saying cant read array (numarray here). Some help in fixing it is most welcome.

```
#! /user/bin/tclsh
puts "Enter sequence count: ";
gets stdin count;
puts "\nEnter the numbers: ";
for {set i 0} {$i < $count} {incr i} {
gets stdin numarray($i);
}

set delstart $numarray(0);
puts "Starting index: " $numarray(0);
set delend $numarray(1);

for {set $i $delstart} {$i < $delend} {incr $i} {
    unset numarray($i);
}

puts "\nNumber array after deletion :";
foreach $i [array names numarray] {
puts "$numarray($i)";
}
```

Comment: A note about Tcl terminology: what other languages call an "array" (a numerically indexed collection of elements), Tcl calls a "list"; what other languages call a "dictionary" or "hash" or "associative array" (a mapping of one "thing" to another "thing"), Tcl calls an "array".

Comment: To print the contents of an array use the `parray`command.

Comment: `foreach $i [array names ...` should be `foreach i [array names ...` without the `$` for the loop variable. Same for `for {set $i ...` should be `for {set i ...`. Same for `incr $i`. When you read the tcl man pages ([`incr`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/incr.htm), [`set`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/set.htm), [`foreach`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/foreach.htm)) be aware when it says `varName`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. fixed it now.

Comment: tcl also has `dict`s, which are also hash tables but with a different API than arrays. Sometimes arrays are more convenient, sometimes dicts are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems throughout the code due to one underlying issue.

Generally speaking, when you want the value of a variable, use the `$` in front.
When you are writing to a variable, use the variable name.

I will use one line from your code as an example:

```
for {set $i $delstart} {$i < $delend} {incr $i} {
```

As it is, the command would be interpreted as:

```
for {set 12 $delstart} {$i < $delend} {incr 12} {
```

`12` is a valid variable name, but not the one you are using.
Should be:

```
for {set i $delstart} {$i < $delend} {incr i} {
```

Only the test `$i < $delend` needs the value.

Comment: In Tcl, unlike in some other languages, `$vbl` _always_ means “read from the variable `vbl`”.